# Atom não salva na codificação correta

Tags: codificação-de-caracteres, utf-8, atom, iso-8859-1

Quando salvo um arquivo pelo *Atom*, ele sempre grava os acentos em *UTF-8*.

Mesmo o arquivo sendo identificando como *ISO-8859-1* (ali na parte inferior).

Então fiz o seguinte teste no terminal:

**Antes de abrir o arquivo:**

```
file -I arquivo.php 
arquivo.php: text/x-php; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Textos corretos: Você não tem permissão.

**Após abrir o arquivo e salvar:**

```
file -I arquivo.php 
arquivo.php: text/x-php; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Textos errados: Voc� n�o tem permiss�o.

Preciso instalar algo para resolver?

Answer (score 1):

É realmente uma limitação, mas isso ajudará,

- http://editorconfig.org/
- https://github.com/sindresorhus/atom-editorconfig#readme

Apenas colocará um arquivo .editorconfig na raiz do teu projeto, ou no diretório que precisar

Exemplo rudimentar:

```
root = true

[*]
charset = iso-8859-1 ou latin1(não lembro)

[*.{json,yml}]
charset = utf-8
```

Comment: Rafael estamos quase lá. Verifiquei e o tipo suportado é latin1. Mas ainda o .editorconfig (na raiz do projeto) não está fazendo efeito. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Baixou o plugin?

`apm install editorconfig` fechou o atom, abriu o arquivo novamente?

Comment: Fiz os passos direitinho, fui em Install, Instalei o editorconfig, reiniciei o Atom e ainda nada.

Answer (score 0):

Nessa [discussão](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/12705) [(e essa)](https://github.com/atom/encoding-selector/issues/8) diz que realmente o atom tem um problema de identificação do tipo de codificação.
Devem estar arrumando.

Comment: É exatamente este problema. Poxa parece que não foi resolvido. :(